# How to disable auto submit behavior when hitting enter key?

Tags: javascript, button

I want to hit enter key to go to p2.htm or p3.htm according to the input text that I was typing in.  And I also want to hit submit1 button to alert('no1') manually.

It works in FireFox, but in IE6, when I hit enter key it will submit the submit button.

How can I make the thing right in IE 6 as it is in FireFox?

I use javascript and jQuery.

```
<input id="Text2"  type="text"  onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13){go2();}" /> 
<input id="Text3"  type="text"  onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13){go3();}" /> 

<input id="submit1"  type="submit" value="submit" onclick="alert('no1')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function go2()
    {
        window.location = "p2.htm";
    }
    function go3()
    {
        window.location = "p3.htm";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```
function submitOnEnter(e, page) {
    var key;

    if (window.event)
        key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
    else
        key = e.which; //Firefox & others

    if(key == 13)
        window.location = page;
}
```

You should call it like this:

```
<input id="Text2"  type="text"  onkeyup="submitOnEnter(event, 'p2.html')" />
```

Comment: There is some mistake but your solution help me out.
<input id="Text1"  type="text" onkeypress="return submitOnEnter(event, 'p2.htm')" /> 
<input id="Text2"  type="text" onkeypress="return submitOnEnter(event, 'p3.htm')" /> 
<input id="submit1"  type="submit" value="submit" onclick="alert('no1')" />

function submitOnEnter(e, page) {
    var key;
    if (window.event)
        key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
    else
        key = e.which; //Firefox & others

    if(key == 13) {
        window.location = page;
        return false; //prevent auto hit submit button
    }
}

Answer (score 42):

If using MVC3, you can disable submitting via Enter by editing the BeginForm call as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will disable the enter key on textarea inside the form.

Comment: I've been digging 4 hours till I found this simple and working solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is by far the simplest and best solution!

Comment: @Santosh See my answer if you need a solution that preserves Enter key functionality within text areas.

Answer (score 27):

```
<form onsubmit="return false"></form>
```

This will stop the form proceeding to the next page after either by clicking a submit button or pressing enter.

Comment: 3 years later and still saving the day. Doesn't get simpler than this.

Comment: What if I only want to disable submit on enter key, but I want to keep the submit on click??

Comment: @sumid, does [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778590/590719) help in that instance?

Comment: @WEFX : If I understand correctly your answer applies only to ASP. I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 12):

The problem with the accepted solution is that normal submit buttons no longer work. You must script all the buttons.

```
<form onsubmit="return false"></form>
```

Here's a better solution that doesn't break non javascript submit buttons. This solution simply tells the browser to not do default behavior when a user hits the enter key on form inputs.

```
// prevent forms from auto submitting on all inputs
$(document).on("keydown", "input", function(e) {
  if (e.which==13) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the input type from "submit" to "button"

Comment: Don't make it break completely when JS isn't available. Build on things that work. http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: To be fair, the OP is locked into a JS solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function stopsubmit()
        {
            document.ourform.onsubmit="return true";
        }
        function pup()
        {
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="sa.jsp" name="ourform" onsubmit="return false">
        <s:submit action="" onclick="stopsubmit()" theme="simple"></s:submit>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".div/formClass").bind("keypress", function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             return false;
          }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form has multi-line text fields (`textarea`), this solution will preserve Enter key functionality within those fields while preventing Enter keypresses from submitting the form:

```
$(document).keypress(function disableEnterKey(event) {  // disable Enter key submit
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13' && event.target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {  // allow newlines
        return false;
    }
});
```