# MVC Html.BeginForm and Javascript ajax calls overlap

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to debug someone else's application, and what happens is that it uses MVC Html.BeginForm clause that creates the HTML  tag, and there's a type="button" element which is used to submit the form.

The page has a Javascript that handles the "onclick" event of that button, which, in turn calls a jQuery ajax script that call the web service on the server.

I managed to catch a bug when I use Enter button, the form is getting submitted twice - through the Html.xxx structure, I suppose, and through that "onclick" event. If I remove the Javascript from the page, it calls the controller's action once, through how it's set up in Html.BeginForm clause.

**CSHTML:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new
{
  id = "forgotPassForm"
}))
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 input-email-forgotPassword">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control form-control-text", Placeholder = @Localization.Email })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" class="forgot_password" id="sendEmailBtn" disabled>@Localization.SendEmail</button>
    <div class="messageWrapper">

        <div id="confirmMessageSent" hidden>
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        <p>@Localization.MailHasBeenSent.</p>
        <p>@Localization.TheLinkWillBeValid.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="errorMessage" hidden>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

@section scripts{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/scripts/Views/Account/ForgotPassword.js"></script>
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
"use strict";

(function (page) {
    page(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function ($, window, document) {

    var Page = {};

    $(function () {
        /// <summary>
        /// DOM is ready!
        /// </summary>
        var currentPage = $(document.getElementById("forgotPassPage"));
        Page.init(null, currentPage);
    });

    Page = {
        model: {},
        page: null,
        el: {},
        init: function (model, page) {
            this.model = model,
                this.page = page,
                this.methods.mapped();
            this.events();
        },
        cache: {
            forgotPassForm: null,
            sendEmailBtn: null,
            confirmMessageSent: null,
            errorMessage: null
        },
        events: function () {
            Page.cache.sendEmailBtn.on("click", Page.methods.sendEmail);
        },
        methods: {
            mapped: function () {
                Page.cache.forgotPassForm = Page.page.find("#forgotPassForm");
                Page.cache.sendEmailBtn = Page.page.find("#sendEmailBtn");
                Page.cache.confirmMessageSent = Page.page.find("#confirmMessageSent");
                Page.cache.errorMessage = Page.page.find("#errorMessage");
            },
            sendEmail: function () {
                /// <summary>
                /// Sends email with restore password instructions
                /// </summary>
                if ($(forgotPassForm).valid()) {
                    var form = $(forgotPassForm).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "/Account/ForgotPassword",
                        data: form,
                        success: function() {
                            $(errorMessage).hide("fast");
                            $(confirmMessageSent).show("fast");
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            $(confirmMessageSent).hide("fast");
                            $(errorMessage).html('<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>' + '<p>' + err.responseJSON + '</p>');
                            $(errorMessage).show("fast");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }


        }
    }

}));
```

**Controller's action:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordEmailModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var userProfile = UnitOfWork.UserService.GetUserProfileByUserEmail(model.Email);
    if (userProfile != null)
    {
    var userFullName = userProfile.FirstName + " " + userProfile.LastName;
    //generate new unique userkey
    string userKey = UniqueKeyHelper.UserKey();
    UnitOfWork.UserService.ChangeUserKey(userProfile, userKey, DateTime.Now);
    Services.EmailService.SendForgotPassEmail(model.Email, userFullName, userKey, this.ControllerContext, Request.Url.Authority);
    return Json(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
    return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Localization.Localization.EmailInvalid);
}
```

I would use only an AJAX call, but not sure how to workaround the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] validation. Anyone can advise me on that?

Mucho thanks in advance!

Comment: The ajax request works at least ? I mean, when you click the button..

Comment: You should use ajax begin form. Example : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-5-ajax-beginform-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-onfailure/

Comment: @Riddhi, No you should not (even MS don't recommend that anymore).

Comment: Probably not related, but your button should be a submit button and your script should handle the forms `.submit()` event so client side validation is triggered on the whole form, and then you cancel the default submit (e.g. `e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The AJAX call actually works all the time until I disable the script. And another time that controller's action is called is in some mysterious way when I hit ENTER button, and it returns a plain 200 on an empty page after the call is finished and returned to the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to disable Html.xxx form submission? I think that would help me? I would use only the AJAX call.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it's a bit too much of code altering, I will consider that if nothing else would work. Thanks!

Comment: What @StephenMuecke said is related to what I have asked. If your ajax works fine, then cancel the default submit behaviour by preventing the form `submit` event and call the ajax within it instead.

Comment: Changing <button type="button" to <input type="button" will stop the form submitting on the button press and run the javascript only

Comment: @sheavens that's how it was initially set up there, but the ENTER hit submits the form anyway, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020940/how-to-disable-auto-submit-behavior-when-hitting-enter-key There are a few answers there that will work (I wouldn't choose the accepted one though)

Comment: Adding this code worked:
                e.preventDefault(); 
I don't know how to mark @Stephen Muecke's answer as a solution!

Comment: @AndreyKorneyev fyi, take a look at this library: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

Comment: @ozum.e "This project is part of ASP.NET Core" -- this is a Framework project :(